# Mongoose - save models array with promise all

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm using mongoose with node v8+.
While save a model to the database i can use `await model.save()`
and  if they are more than one model i can use `await Promise.all([model1.save(),model2.save()])`

what if the models was in array

example

```
models=[];
models[0]=new Model(..);
models[1]=new Model(..);
.....
```

how can i call save on all these models at once in promise.all ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For parallel saving:

```
 await Promise.all(models.map(model => model.save()))
```

Or one after another:

```
 for(const model of models)
    await model.save();
```

Comment: will the for loop execute in parallel too ?

Comment: No. It will execute `one after another`

Comment: In promise.all example, what happens if one model fails to save? Will the other models save without the failed model? Or will all the models fail to save?

Comment: @cocacrave all will be saved. but the `Promise.all` will be rejected (and you should handle that). In the *one after another* snippet it will break.